# Firestore startAt returning null

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to use a cursor, however whenever I query this I don't get any results.  For example, the below returns `0, null`

```
const next = admin.firestore().collectionGroup('extItems')
    .where('platform', "==", "mba")
    .orderBy('created_at')
    .startAt('7F6JDHOd6c9cXZqclaVf')
    .limit(100);

const result = await next.get();

console.log(result.docs.length)
if(result.docs.length <= 0) console.log("null")
```

I've ran this query without the startAt and its fine. It also doesn't seem to matter which documentId I use as a cursor either.

[image]
Not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Please add also a screenshot with the content of a document.

Comment: I think i've just realised what I'm doing wrong.  I need to be setting the document as the cursor, not the document ID..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way you can pass a document id `7F6JDHOd6c9cXZqclaVf` to the `startAt()` function and expect to return all the documents that are after that id. In Cloud Firestore you cannot do that because the documents are not in an order so you can know from where to start. If you want to use that function, you shold pass the value of a property that exsits within your document.

Comment: That would make sense. In my document, I have an ID field.  I've just updated my question with how I get that ID (self implemented queue service using FB triggers) however I'm still getting `0, null`.

Comment: The updated question has nothing to do with the initial one. Changing the query in that way, makes this question to be a new one. So I have rolled it back to the initial state. If you have hard times with the new query, please post another fresh question, so me and other Firebase developers can help you.